# How to store GeoLocation in model class in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, json, rest, user-interface

So this is JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "address" : {
            "street" : "VanderWyk",
            "housenumber" : "456",
            "postalcode" : "3061 WL GA",
            "city" : "Roterdam",
            "geoLocation" : {
                "lat" : "50.555011",
                "lng" : "5.894267"
            }
        },
        "type" : "PWS"
    }, {
        address...
    }
]
```

I know how to handle single objects but I don't know how to handle `geoLocation` which is Json object in itself. To define it as an String array? How should I store this in a model class? Database? And then when I'm consuming this data from front-end..what will be easiest way to do that? How to write REST service to do such a thing?

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a JSON-seralizer such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Then, for example, you can have a `GeoLocation` class. Then your main object class can have a property that is an instance of `GeoLocation`. When de-seralizing the JSON, it will interpret the `geoLocation` field in the JSON and create a `GeoLocation` object for it.

Comment: Yeah I could try that.